# User Mentions in Website Using Algolia & Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, algolia

I am currently using Algolia to index my user data and Typeahead to provide autocomplete search results and I really like how it all works.

Now, I'm curious about adding mentions (@user) to my website in textareas and figure that there should be a "fairly" simple way of using javascript to identify whenever I use the "@" symbol in the textarea, initialize Typeahead, and allow me to autocomplete the user in my text.

Does anyone have any ideas to do that? Maybe using:

```
if (string.indexOf("@") > -1 )
{
   // initialize typeahead
}
```

Not sure if it could be that simple...

Thanks!

Comment: Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: Right, sorry, should've included that in the code snippet instead of being assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should find everything you need just there: https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/autocomplete-textarea

> One approach is to use Javascript plugins & scripts that perform, most
>   of the time, very basic text search (based on regex) on items already
>   pre-populated in the HTML, or dynamically retrieved from the database
>   via AJAX requests. Those solutions work OK, but quickly show their
>   limits as soon as you want to offer to your users a search experience
>   that handles their typos, is fast, and can work on hundreds, thousands
>   or millions of items.